# python os.path.getsize different than len(f.read())

Tags: python, file, fread

I have a file file.txt

doing

```
print os.path.getsize(filename)
```

outputs

> 6510

and doing

```
print len(open(filename).read())
```

gets me

> 6355

how come ? 
i am using windows 7. if i look on the file properties in windows explorer it says

> Size: 6.35 KB (6,510 bytes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`open(filename)` opens `filename` in text mode.

This means that every `\r\n` (carriage return, line feed) will be translated to a single `\n` in your Python string.

Seems like your file is 155 lines long.

Comment: Why would the windows explorer return that number ?

Comment: @madjar: Because the file does contain all those CRLFs, and Python removes all the CRs when reading the file, because Python strings only use LF as a newline character.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: no, I think madjar is asking why *Windows* returns both 6.35 KB and 6510.  Does Explorer do the same conversion?

Comment: @DSM: 6510 / 1024 = 6,357421875. That's why.
Its pure coincidence that it looks like the `read()` number of characters relates to the  bytes translated to kilobytes. If the content of the file had been written in one line or all `\n` instead of CRLF they'd be equal.

Answer (score -3):

This is because when a file is saved on the disk, the filesystem also uses some extra bytes to store different properties of the file, like Creation Date and Last Modified date. When you do

```
print os.path.getsize(filename)
```

It gets the size of the actual file on disk.

But if you do

```
print len(open(filename).read())
```

you just get the length of contents or the data stored in your file which is always lesser.

Exactly for this reason the Properties Window of Windows Explorer shows you Size (i.e- the actual length of the file's contents) and Size on Disk, the number of bytes actually occupied by the file on the disk.

Comment: Nope. Filesystem metadata is pretty much never included in the file size. And even if it were, the difference would be a multiple of the disk sector size.